# Can I use Select from Insert into table function in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, date-arithmetic

I got the following dataset:

```
CREATE temp TABLE XXX (DATE TEXT, PRICE INTEGER);
INSERT INTO XXX VALUES 
('2019-04-27 01:00', 1), ('2019-04-27 02:30', 3), ('2019-04-27 18:00',2), 
('2019-04-28 17:00', 2), ('2019-04-28 21:00', 5), 
('2019-04-29 17:00',50), ('2019-04-29 21:00',10), 
('2019-04-30 17:00',10), ('2019-04-30 21:00',20), 
('2019-05-01 17:00',40), ('2019-05-01 21:00',10), 
('2019-05-02 17:00',10), ('2019-05-02 21:00', 6);
```

Then I tried to use this query to take 2 recent rows from table `XXX` and add them with `date` + 1 day and same `price` values to table `XXX`. As a result, rows with date 05-03 should be added.

```
with A as (
select * from XXX
order by DATE DESC),

B as (select * from (insert into A (DATE, PRICE),
select * from A
limit 2))

select * from B
```

Here I got an error:

> ```
> error at or near "insert"
> ```

How can tackle this issue?

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify a bit as I understood the question. Please adjust if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
with i as (
       insert into A (DATE, PRICE)
           select * 
           from XXX
           order by DATE TEXT DESC
           limit 2
           returning *
      )
select *
from i;
```

Comment: You meant ''' with A as (
select * from XXX
order by DATE TEXT DESC),i as (
       insert into A (DATE, PRICE)
           select * 
           from XXX
           order by DATE TEXT DESC
           limit 2
           returning *
      )
select *
from i;) ?

Comment: @JohnMayer  . . . Are you really trying to insert into a CTE?  That is not allowed.

Comment: yes, I wanted. Are there any other alternatives how to do this manipulation? May be kind of create 2 CTE and then use UNION, but I do not know how.

Comment: @JohnMayer . . . You can only insert into tables or certain views.

Comment: Now I understood. I solved it by using  CTE A and B  in select and then used UNION ALL to create a table from these two CTEs. However, how can I add 1 day to table B? SELECT  add_date(DATE), Price did not help

Answer (score 0):

I *think*, you just want to:

```
INSERT INTO xxx (date, price)
SELECT date + 1  -- adding a day to a date
     , price
FROM   xxx
ORDER  BY date DESC
LIMIT  2;
```

This takes the latest two rows according to column `date`, adds a day and inserts new rows.

Optionally append `RETURNING *` to also return the rows you just inserted.

It might break if ...

- ... the column `date` is not type `date` (rather don't use basic type names as identifer)
- ... `date` is not defined `NOT NULL`.
- ... there are not exactly two rows for the latest day.

The operation [`date + integer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) adds days to a date in Postgres. Related:

- [How do I determine the last day of the previous month using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944721/how-do-i-determine-the-last-day-of-the-previous-month-using-postgresql/8945281#8945281)
- [Find out number of months between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727543/find-out-number-of-months-between-2-dates/23739871#23739871)